# angular2 Type 'Subject<{}>' is not assignable to type '() => Subject<number>'

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, multicast

i use angular2 rxjs to test it's multicast func,here is my code:

```
var source = Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);
var subject = new Subject();
var multicasted = source.multicast(subject);

// These are, under the hood, `subject.subscribe({...})`:
multicasted.subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)
});
multicasted.subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)
});

// This is, under the hood, `source.subscribe(subject)`:
multicasted.connect();
```

i got the error info :

Argument of type 'Subject<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type

```
'Subject<number> | (() => Subject<number>)'.
        Type 'Subject<{}>' is not assignable to type '() => Subject<number>'.
        Type 'Subject<{}>' provides no match for the signature '(): Subject<number>'
```

Comment: Try `var subject = new Subject<number>();`

Comment: Try var subject = new Subject<any>(); if type is not important to you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like @yurzui says, you need to define the type of generic Subject

```
var subject = new Subject<number>();
```